# Payment API Gateway

Tags: redirect, google-api, request, ip-address, gateway

I am developing an application, in which I have a payment method API to make payments. But to call this API I have to give access to the IP address which is calling it, which is not possible for a production app, as there are lot of users with different IP addresses.
I want to have a single gateway where a user can request for the payment and that gateway with it IP address initialise the payment method by calling the payment method API with it IP address. Is there any way to achieve this goal, Via google service or anything?

I am searching for google service mainly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is basically not of coding but for a service solution or a platform solution. I want my payment api to be called from a single gateway or IP address on behalf of other app users.